# Error: The method or property expo-app-auth.authAsync is not available on ios, are you sure you've linked all the native dependencies properly?

Tags: react-native, expo, google-authentication

expo-app-auth: 11.1.0

I was trying to use the Google API auth from expo in react native, but when the user clicks a button to prompt the API, nothing happens and I get the following error:

[image]

here is my code:

```
import React, { createContext, useContext } from 'react';
import * as Google from "expo-google-app-auth";


const AuthContext = createContext({});

const config = {
  androidClientId: Key,
  iosClientId: Key,
  scopes: ['profile', 'email'],
  permissions: ['public_profile', 'email', 'gender', 'location'],
}

export const AuthProvider = ({children}) => {

const signInWithGoogle = async () => {
    Google.logInAsync(config).then(async (logInResult) => {
      if(logInResult.type === 'success'){

      }
    });
};

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value ={{
        user: null,
        signInWithGoogle
    }}
    >
       {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default function useAuth() {
    return useContext(AuthContext);
}
```

I have GoogleService-Info.plist file in my project, but it still does not work. Also, I am aware that expo-google-app-auth is deprecated, but I am not sure how to migrate, since this should work.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. I resolved the issue by downgrading expo-google-app-auth to version 8.3.0.

Remove the dependency from your expo project using
`npm uninstall expo-google-app-auth` or `yarn remove expo-google-app-auth`
and try installing the specific version by
`npm install expo-google-app-auth@8.3.0` or `yarn add expo-google-app-auth@8.3.0`.

Also, make sure that you have added **fingerprints** both (**SHA256 and SHA1**) in your firebase project.

I was able to resolve the issue by following the above steps. Hope it helps.

Comment: I have downgraded, unfortunately, I am getting the same message.

Comment: Does your firebase app has both the fingerprints added?

Comment: Yes, the firebase app does have both fingerprints added. Not sure why it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

'expo-google-app-auth' package is now deprecated. So, You have 2 options

You can change 'expo-auth-session' for your project. for more info: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v43.0.0/sdk/auth-session/

or follow the steps:

1. rm -r -fo .\node_modules = for delete node modules directory
2. "expo": "~44.0.0" => change expo version in your package.json file
3. npm i or yarn => install all dependencies
4. expo doctor --fix-dependencies => for change all dependencies to correct versions
5. expo start => finally, start your project

Now, I hope your google login working

*Happy coding*

Comment: Hi!
I am currently working on app using snack online editor and I am getting the same error. Any idea how can that be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

**STEP1:** Downgrade Expo
**STEP2:** Downgrade React

I have attached my dependencies of `package.json` file for your reference.

```
    "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.11",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.7.0",
    "expo": "~44.0.0",
    "expo-google-app-auth": "8.3.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.11.7",
    "firebase": "9.6.11",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.7",
    "tailwind-rn": "^4.2.0",
    "tailwindcss-react-native": "^1.7.10"
  },
```